# fullCalendar - Change cell color of a period of time

Tags: css, colors, fullcalendar

I want to change cell color of a period of time. Ex: change to green, the color of the cells from 9 am to 11 am of the day 2016-01-20.

I've been searching for a solution about a week, but every tip is about changing all day using

`$(".fc-day[data-date='2016-01-20']").css('background', 'green');`

And that is not what I need.

regards.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code (html, css, js) ideally a jsFiddle demo

Comment: Relevant code? really? Wasn't the title and description enough to understand the context? I am talking about FullCalendar and saying that I don't know what to do to solve the problem. Could you provide some relevant comment? Sometimes I think people here just want to minus a question to get a new badge. But... thank you anyway. Like a miracle, I found the solution I've been searching for since a week, just after posting the question.

Comment: my friend I'm sorry if my request had upset you. BTW I did not vote down your question. have a nice day and I'm happy you found a solution

Comment: @Aziz What made me upset was the minus in my question, not your request, because it is not good for the reputation. If weren't you that vote down my question, so the one who needs to apologize is me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new version of fullCalendar, provides a backgrouEvent

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
defaultDate: '2016-01-20',
defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
events: [
    {
        start: '2016-01-20T09:00:00',
        end: '2016-01-20T11:00:00',
        rendering: 'background'
    }
]});
```